# MongoDB query for latest data?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Pretty much my data looks something like this:

```
{
"name" : "Name1",
"monthson" : "4",
"data" : "OLD DATA FOR 1"
},
{
"name" : "Name1",
"monthson" : "5",
"data" : "LATEST DATA FOR 1"
},
{
"name" : "Name2",
"monthson" : "7",
"data" : "OLD DATA FOR 2"
},
{
"name" : "Name2",
"monthson" : "8",
"data" : "LATEST DATA FOR 2"
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to group everything by each name and then output the latest Data. (monthson represents how many months each set has been active so the highest monthson is the most recent).

My Mongo query looks something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
        [
            {$match: {$in: ["name1", "name2"]}}
            {$group:
            {
                _id:"$name",
                monthson:{$max: "$monthson"},
                data: {$addToSet: "$data"}
            }},
        ])
```

The output looks like this:

```
{
_id:"Name1",
monthson: 5,
data: ["OLD DATA FOR 1", " LATEST DATA FOR 1"]
}
{
_id:"Name2",
monthson: 8,
data: ["LATEST DATA FOR 2", "OLD DATA FOR 2"]
}
```

The trick is every time I run this query it adds every set of data to my result when I only want the data that corresponds to the highest monthson. I can't query for first, last or highest data because they will always be in random order.

Comment: Pro-tip: don't beg for help "ASAP" here, but do [read this community discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/472495).

Answer (score 3):

You can use **$sort** to get the order you want (I used oldest first), and then **$first** to get to the first (oldest) matching record for each **"name"**:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {name: {$in: ["Name1", "Name2"]}}
    },
    {
        $sort: {monthson:-1}
    },
    {   
        $group: {
                _id:"$name",
                first:{$first: "$$ROOT"}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! the sorting with the $$ROOT works however I just realized some of the records have the same number of monthson but different sets of data. Is there a way to pull all the records with the highest monthson in one query?